# Word's definition dialog in android

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, spannablestring

I'm building a language learning app in **Android**, I want to make a feature that when we click on a word in a paragraph it shows a mini dialog next to the word to supply the definition of the word.
I'm trying overriding *onTouchListener* with *spannable string* for a textview (a single textview contains a paragraph) because I want to know the location of the click to know where to show the dialog.

But the problem is it just works correctly with the function of the onTouchListener (retrieving the location), I can't click on the spanned I've made.
Could anybody suggest for me a way to go? **Thank you very much.**
[This is what I want, it's from the app Hello Chinese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDmzH.png)